# C++ Boost ?<= Lookbehind expression error syntax

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, boost

необходимо реализовать регулярное выражение, которое парсит из файла директивы препроцессора #include "" <>, необходимо регулярное выражение, которое учитывает, что перед #include могут быть только пробелы, между #include и "" или <> , тоже должны отсутствовать символы (кроме пробелов) и необходимо доставать имена заголовочных файлов в кавычках. Была попытка реализовать следующее выражение:

```
(?<=^[\s]*#include[\s]+)((")|(<))[\w]+((\.h)|(\.cpp))((")|(>))
```

regextesting https://www.regextester.com/97722, отображает, что регулярное выражение отрабатывает корректно, однако компилятор выдаёт ошибку о неправильном использовании регулярного выражения.

Comment: Извините, но `(?<=^[\s]*#include[\s]+)((")|(<))[\w]+((.h)|(.cpp))((")|(>))` на regextester.com отображается как невалидное. Это, кстати, верно как в отношении C++ `std::regex`, так и `boost::regex`: там оно работать не будет из-за блока предварительного просмотра назад с шаблоном неопределённой длины. Ещё раз ксати, этот блок тут вообще не нужен.

Answer (score -1):

Парсить С++ регулярками не получится. Для парсинга директив препроцессора необходимо реализовать полноценный препроцессор. Собственно исходные предположения о виде директивы `#include` неверные. Директива может выглядеть например вот так:

```
#define IO <iostream> // где-то выше

#include \
    IO
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за Ваш ответ, займусь изучением возможных вариаций директивы #include, однако не могли бы вы всё-таки дать совет, как должно выглядеть регулярное выражение, для приведённого мною случая?